# How to find if a String in an ArrayList contains a digit in as a char

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, hashmap

There is a `HashMap` Having id and name. Name has some constraints. The Strings which match the criteria should be added to an `ArrayList`.

i) First character should be small and the last character should be Capital.
ii) In name at least one digit should be there.

Example: `ravi5raJ`

```
public static ArrayList<String> getName(HashMap<Integer,String> map) {
    ArrayList<String> a1=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Integer key: map.keySet()) {
        int size=map.get(key).length();
        String name= map.get(key);
        int count=0;
        if(name.substring(0, 1)== name.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase())
        {
            if(name.substring(size-1, size-1)==name.substring(size-1, size-1).toUpperCase())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
                    //logic to check for int
                    a1.add(name);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return a1;
}
```

Comment: And what is it that you don't know how to do? What have you tried? ...

Comment: When comparing equality of Strings in Java, use myString1.equals(myString2) instead of the == operator, as String is an object and not a primitive data type like an int or char.

Comment: yes i tried parsing each char in the String to int. During matching even if there is a single match of int type I would add it to ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can test everything with a simple regex:

```
if( name.matches( "[a-z].*?\\d.*[A-Z]" ) ){ ...
```

Comment: Thank You While working I spent 1 hour with this and didn't think of regex. I think I was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly now.

```
  public static ArrayList<String> getName(HashMap<Integer,String> map) {
            ArrayList<String> a1=new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Integer key: map.keySet()) {
                int size=map.get(key).length();
                String name= map.get(key);
                int count=0;
                if( name.matches( "[a-z].*?\\d.*[A-Z]" ) )
                    a1.add(name);

            }
            return a1;
        }
```